# Getting tf / tfidf from sklearn output

Tags: python, scikit-learn

My data frame is

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"person":['A','B','C'],"url":["google.kr","stackoverflow.com","yahoo.us"],"weight":[5,10,15]})
df2 = df.loc[np.repeat(df.index.values,df.weight)]
```

tfidf is:

```
v = TfidfVectorizer(token_pattern='\S+',smooth_idf=False,norm=None)
x = v.fit_transform(df2['url'])
```

and I extract idf using

```
v.idf_
```

which give idf in nice formatted array.

I am struggling with extracting either tfidf or only tf.

```
# for tfidf
x.toarray()
# for tf 
v = CountVectorizer(token_pattern='\S+')
x = v.fit_transform(df2['url'])
x.toarray()
```

This gives me a array containing only 0,1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the term frequency (TF), the count vectorizer is counting the occurrences of each token in every row of your `df2`. In other words, when you look at `df2` you see that a single token would be present in each row, and that is why it is 1 or 0. So, you must sum each columns counts to get term frequency across the entire dataframe, which I assume is what you are after?

```
# for tf 
v = CountVectorizer(token_pattern='\S+')
x = v.fit_transform(df2['url'])

# gets term frequencies for each token
[sum(l) for l in list(zip(*x.toarray()))] 

# see which tokens are which element
v.vocabulary_
```

Output

```
[5, 10, 15]
{'google.kr': 0, 'stackoverflow.com': 1, 'yahoo.us': 2}
```

The `zip` method just unnests each 'column' from the array. You can learn more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp) if you have not seen it before.

And the IDF you already know so TF-IDF is `tf * idf`.